# What is the equivalent of the null-safe equality operator <=> in SQLite?

Tags: mysql, database, sqlite, null, operator-keyword

I need to determine what is the equivalent for SQLite of the [<=> operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to) in MySQL.

Any idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> The IS and IS NOT operators work like = and != except when one or both
>   of the operands are NULL. In this case, if both operands are NULL,
>   then the IS operator evaluates to 1 (true) and the IS NOT operator
>   evaluates to 0 (false)

http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#isisnot

Answer (score 2):

I have just found the "IS" operator, but not sure if it has exactly the same behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

From
[2022-06-25 (3.39.0)](https://www.sqlite.org/changes.html#version_3_39_0):

> Add new binary comparison operators **IS NOT DISTINCT FROM** and **IS DISTINCT FROM** that are equivalent to IS and IS NOT, respective, for compatibility with PostgreSQL and SQL standards.

> [IS NOT DISTINCT FROM](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#isdf):
>
> **The IS NOT DISTINCT FROM** operator is an alternative spelling for the IS operator. Likewise, the IS DISTINCT FROM operator means the same thing as IS NOT. Standard SQL does not support the compact IS and IS NOT notation. Those compact forms are an SQLite extension. You have to use the prolix and much less readable IS NOT DISTINCT FROM and IS DISTINCT FROM operators on other SQL database engines.

Sample:

```
CREATE TABLE test(col1 INT, col2 INT);

INSERT INTO test(col1, col2)
VALUES (0, 0), (0, 1), (0, NULL), (1, 0), (1, 1), (NULL, 0), (NULL, NULL);
```

Query:

```
SELECT *, col1 IS NOT DISTINCT FROM col2 AS "<=>"
FROM  test;
```

Output:

[image]

**[db<>fiddle demo - SQLite](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.39&fiddle=d6f217a88e9f9814b30d762b4d06f200)**

[db<>fiddle demo - PostgreSQL](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=d6f217a88e9f9814b30d762b4d06f200)