# Python SQLite delete where value is "None"

Tags: python, sqlite

I need to delete DB entries where the value could be None. I get my values from a ListBox.
The function looks like this:

```
    def OnDelete(self, e): 
    num = self.list.GetItemCount()
    for i in range(num):
        if self.list.IsChecked(i):
            itemValueList = []
            for i2 in range(6):
                item = self.list.GetItem(i, i2)

                if item.GetText() == "None":
                    itemValueList.append("")
                else:
                    itemValueList.append(item.GetText()) 

    DBManager.DeleteEntry(itemValueList)
```

And the function in my DBManager looks like this:

```
def DeleteEntry(itemValueList):
    # Open Database
    conn = sqlite3.connect('Database.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    # Delete a row of data
    c.execute('delete from Database where Value1=? and Value2=? and Value3=? and Value4=? and Value5=? and Value6=?',  
              (itemValueList[0], itemValueList[1], itemValueList[2], itemValueList[3], itemValueList[4], itemValueList[5]))

    # Save (commit) the changes
    conn.commit()
```

So in my case at the moment Value5 and Value6 are "None" or NULL in the SQLite DB. Therefore i set the string added to the itemValueList to "". But that doesnt work. The DB Entriy doesnt get deleted.

What do i have to change that also Entries where some columns can have no value are getting deleted?

Thank you.

[EDIT]:

```
c.execute('delete from Database where isnull(Value1,"")=? and isnull(Value2,"")=? and isnull(Value3,"")=? and isnull(Value4,"")=? and isnull(Value5,"")=? and isnull(Value6,"")=?',  
          (itemValueList[0], itemValueList[1], itemValueList[2], itemValueList[3], itemValueList[4], itemValueList[5]))
```

Comment: An empty string is not the same thing as `NULL`. To match a null value in SQL you have to use `columnName IS NULL`, you can't use `=`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQL (and especially, SQLite), the value `NULL` is not identical to the empty string. So, setting the string in the `itemValueList` to the empty string makes no sense. You will need to change your SQL query to allow for the `NULL` value like:

```
delete
  from Database
 where     Value1=?
       and Value2=?
       and Value3=?
       and Value4=?
       and Value5 is null
       and Value6=?
```

And use that form of the query if your Value5 is `None`, or you need to convert your NULL values to the empty string:

```
delete
  from Database
 where     isnull(Value1,'') =?
       and isnull(Value2,'') =?
       and isnull(Value3,'') =?
       and isnull(Value4,'') =?
       and isnull(Value5,'') =?
       and isnull(Value6,'') =?
```

Comment: How do I use that if every value could be NULL. I dont know what values are NULL.

Comment: @K-Doe Use the same phrase as I showed for `Value5` for every value maybe?! I'll update my answer

Comment: I tried to convert my code with yours. But now i get: OperationalError: near "isnull": syntax error. I Add is to my post.

Comment: @K-Doe You are using double quotes. SQL does not know about double quotes. Use single quotes, as I did in the SQL in my answer. SQL is not Python and you cannot interchange double and single quotes.

Comment: Got it! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

See [What is the equivalent of the null-safe equality operator <=> in SQLite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9658125/what-is-the-equivalent-of-the-null-safe-equality-operator-in-sqlite). You should use the `IS` operator instead of `=` in your query, and it will match a `NULL` value properly.

You then need to change the code to use Python `None` rather than an empty string. This will be translated to SQL `NULL` in the prepared statement.

```
            if item.GetText() == "None":
                itemValueList.append(None)
            else:
                itemValueList.append(item.GetText())
```